# Как адаптировать слайдер Slick.js для IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, slick.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно адаптировать Slick под IE? Не хочет работать в нём, слайды все раскинуты, переподключил сегодня версию jquery самую свежую, думал в этом дело, но ничего не изменилось, консоль в IE ошибок не выдаёт, но и не работает ничего. В остальных браузерах слайдер работает как часы, причём с моими изменениями, настройками, абсолютным позиционированием, согласно макета. Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: тёска - ie протух уже , для чего его поддерживать ?

Comment: Согласен с Вами. Ну а если заказчик, который дал мне макет для вёрстки, потребует полной кроссбраузерности?

Comment: на врядли на ie он захочет увидить свой макет

Comment: Я начинающий верстальщик, точно не знаю) Хотелось бы верить что заказчики будут так думать. Спасибо.

Comment: щас уже edge на webkit а вы об ie думаете :))